# javascript 3D animation using images or svg

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, 3d

Hi I want to built a web page which would show the 3D animation shown in the picture below

[image: shape 3d transform]

I have been using the canvas element but it only supports 2D I know there is webGL and Library like three.js But it does not support the kind of animation I need all the elements shown in the picture will be moving at some rate giving a 3D feel I also tries few Libraries like KUTE.js
But it does not have option to use the different images or SVG as use them in a 3D model.

Answer (score 1):

SVGs don't support 3D transformation yet, however you can use the [SVGPathCommander](https://thednp.github.io/svg-path-commander/) to apply a 3D projection to your shapes.

This means that your paths' path commands get moved in the 2D space to create realistic projections of your shapes.

[image: shape 3d transform]

Have fun!